# How can I playback audio as it's being streamed to a file?

Tags: python, file, streaming, text-to-speech, audio-streaming

I'm using [edge-TTS](https://github.com/rany2/edge-tts/tree/master) (text-to-speech software) that streams audio to a file as its being generated. Is there a way to do some processing and then playback this audio as soon as it gets generated and not when it finishes? I'm not too sure how to do this but it seems like it should be possible. The particular code that is being used is in this script from the authors: https://github.com/rany2/edge-tts/blob/master/examples/basic_audio_streaming.py

I'm guessing what this does is continuously streams audio as soon as it's generated to a text file, now I'm wondering how can I do a little processing to the audio as soon as it arrives and play it back while streaming.